# Why can't I execute shell script via crontab?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, crontab

I have this script `shell1.sh` ubicate in `/home/documents/files`, the script is for the creation of users on Linux, so it asks for some information and later creates the user.

I want it to run for every minute all days, so I tried this via crontab modifying with the command `crontab -e`. That's the result with `crontab -l`(I tried this in different ways).

```
*/1 * * * * cd /home/documents/files && sh shell1.sh
*/1 * * * * root cd /home/documents/files && sh shell1.sh
*/1 * * * * /home/usuarios/lab4/shell5.sh
```

But it's not working, I read similar questions, but no answer worked.

What can i try?

Edit:

I changed the crontab to:

```
* * * * * cd /home/documents/files && sh shell1.sh
* * * * * root cd /home/documents/files && sh shell1.sh
* * * * * /home/usuarios/lab4/shell5.sh
* * * * * /bin/date >> /tmp/cron-runs.log
```

The script (very simple) is the following:

```
exit=1
while [ $exit -eq 1 ];do
case=0
read case

case $case in
    1) 
        echo 'nombre del usuario'
        read nombre
        echo 'escriba el nombre del grupo'
        read nombreG
        useradd $nombre -g "$nombreG"
    *) exit=0
esac
done
```

The idea is: execute that program to add users and groups, and ask if you want to do it. I am trying every minute to do it faster.

Nothing happens. I tried to print something but got no results.

Comment: that looks like it should work. Cron will send you mail about execution of your crontab jobs. Log in to a terminal as the user where the crontab is installed and run `mail` and see what messages you've got.

Comment: What happens if you change "*/1"  to "*" - also, what happens if you add an additional line to your cron like * * * * * /bin/date >> /tmp/cron-runs.log.   Also, I note either your first and third command or more likely second command is incorrect.  /etc/cron requires the 6th column to be a user, user crons don't have that - so "root" is not a valid field.

Comment: How is the script going to ask for "some information"? If you manage to run it from cron, it will have no controlling terminal and it will not be able to interact with the desktop, if any (unless you deliberately handle(d) this issue). There are other possible problems (what's good in querying the user each minute? what's good in creating a new user each minute? does the script timeout or detect its previous instances, so it doesn't become a slo-mo forkbomb? maybe a script that starts once and loops is enough?), but you're free to run weird code, why not.

Comment: #!/bin/sh or #!/bin/bash

Comment: Please include information about what you expect the scripts to do, and what actually happens instead.

Comment: (1) Did you test the script by just running it in an interactive shell? It lacks `;;` in the `case` syntax. (2) When run from `cron`, the script will have no terminal to `read` from. Cron is not the right way to run scripts that interact with the user. (3) If you want to "do it more faster", why won't you run the script in a loop? (without cron). // Frankly the question looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). Your real goal is to add multiple users fast, not run something from cron; right?